# Exclude specific iOS devices from Flurry analysis

Tags: flurry

is it possible to exclude specific developer iOS devices from Flurry analysis?

Our userbase is still small enough that our iOS devices can have a significant impact on the analytics.

All I could find on the subject was this from Flurry which I'm hoping is not the definitive answer!

http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ#Is_there_a_way_to_ignore_.22test.22_data_or_specific_devices_for_analytics.3F

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice in Flurry to separate your own internal testing data from live user data is to create two projects for your app, as the link you posted mentions.  Alternatively, you can filter the data by date range (depending on when the app went live) or by version number (if you have a different test version vs. live version).

Comment: Thanks - I think that is the only way.  Issue is that people in the business use the "production" version of the app for ourselves and given our small user base, we end up skewing the data.  I guess the solution is getting a bigger user base!